# Maximum value of range of values in array (C++)

Tags: range, max

The array ampVal has 25600 integers inside it. I need to find the maximum value of each set of 1024 values in the array and store it in another array. However I'm not getting this part to work it only gives 21 values and a random number '1348410436'. ampVal is a dynamic array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

ifstream miniProject;
int n = 0;
miniProject.open("C:\\Users\\Simeon Ramjit\\Desktop\\audioframes.txt");
if (!miniProject) {
    cout << "File not found" << endl;
}
else {
    cout<<"File Located ! :D \nCounting Lines in file..." << endl;

    while (miniProject) {
        string lines;
        getline(miniProject, lines);
        n++;

    }
    cout << "Number of lines in file are: " << n << endl;
    miniProject.close();
}

int *frNum = new int[n];
int *bitNum = new int[n];
int *ampVal = new int[n];
     for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
         frNum[i] = 0;
         bitNum[i] = 0;
         ampVal[i] = 0;
   }




miniProject.open("C:\\Users\\Simeon Ramjit\\Desktop\\audioframes.txt");
if (!miniProject) {
    cout << "File not found" << endl;
}
else {
    int i = 0; 
    string frameNumber, bitNumber, amplitudeValue;
    while (miniProject) {
        (miniProject >> frameNumber >> bitNumber >> amplitudeValue);
        stringstream(frameNumber) >> frNum[i];
        stringstream(bitNumber) >> bitNum[i];
        stringstream(amplitudeValue) >> ampVal[i];
        i++;

    }
}
miniProject.close();


int frameGroupStart = 0;
int frameGroupEnd = 1024;
int maxAmpVal = 0;
while (frameGroupEnd != 25600) {
    for (int i = frameGroupStart; i < frameGroupEnd; i++) {
        if (ampVal[i] >maxAmpVal) {
            maxAmpVal = ampVal[i];
            cout << maxAmpVal << endl;
        }
    }
    frameGroupStart = frameGroupStart + 1024;
    frameGroupEnd = frameGroupEnd + 1024;
}





getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You'll have to show more code.

Comment: Your `frameGroupStart` always stays 0. `frameGroupStart = frameGroupStart + 0;` does never move the starting location of your frame-groups. Shouldn't it also be increased by 1024?

Comment: @cwschmidt Yes, it should, I'll make the change and see what happens...    Well now it gives two more random numbers like the one listed in the question and the program crashes

Comment: This loop `for (int i = 0; i <= n;i++)` runs beyond bounds. Should be `for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)`.

Comment: @cwschmidt Well it doesn't crash or gives me random numbers but now I just have 20 values

Comment: @blazs There you go :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an alternate approach and this gets the job done:

```
int bitGroupStart = 0;
int bitGroupEnd = 1024;
int arrayOfMaxAmpVal[25];
int frameNumMaxVal[25];
int maxAmpVal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    for (int j = bitGroupStart; j < bitGroupEnd; j++) {
        if (ampVal[j] > maxAmpVal) {
            maxAmpVal = ampVal[j];
        }
    }
    bitGroupStart = bitGroupStart + 1024;
    bitGroupEnd = bitGroupEnd + 1024;
    arrayOfMaxAmpVal[i] = maxAmpVal;
    frameNumMaxVal[i] = i;
    maxAmpVal = 0;
}
```